# New Relic on Open source

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, newrelic, newrelic-platform

We are planning to use New Relic on our website hosted in AWS.

What would be the best option - using the copy / paste javascript or install agent?

I am new to new relic monitoring. I thought I can use Install agent, but it looks like I have to expose the licence key. This is an open source project, so exposing the licence key is not an option. Is there any alternative to that?

If I go with copy/paste Javascript, Do I need to paste the script on every page?

Can someone throw best practice here?

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of New Relic monitoring including server monitoring, application monitoring and browser monitoring. Also if your application has other components such as a database, there will be a separate monitoring agent for that.

I'm assuming you are asking about node.js application monitoring since you tagged your question with node.js. Best practice here is to configure the newrelic.js settings script to pull your `app_name` and `license_key` values from a system environment variable instead of adding them directly to the source.

Comment: Great. If the application is in AWS, how can I use an environment variable? should I use nconf and keep the configuration seperate?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's running on an EC2 server, correct?

Comment: True. Its running on EC2 server.

Comment: Then set the environment variable however you normally would in the OS running on the EC2 server.